# How to change mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a problem in converting mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy date format using VBA.

I have a table like this:

[image]

fyi, the table is auto generated from a reporting tool. 
Can "string manipulation" or any excel function help? Hope anyone who know how to solve this problem can give me some idea.

Comment: I assume the date pairs are in a single cell.  Are the pairs separated by a dash or {space dash space}??

Answer (score 3):

Well, from the way you've worded your question I'm not convinced you actually want or need VBA.

Looking at the image you posted it would appear the first cell contains the string `05/06/2013 - 05/10/2013` not the date `05/06/2013`. So the first thing you need to do is split out the parts so the built in Excel or VBA functions can convert it.

### By Excel Formulas

So we could use SEARCH or FIND to find the "-" and do things dynamically. But I'm feeling lazy so I'll just assume the first 10 characters of the string are the first date and the last 10 characters are the second date. A TRIM function on the source string should make this a bit safer in case of extra spaces before or after.

So if our string `05/06/2013 - 05/10/2013` is in cell A2, we can put `=LEFT(TRIM(A2),10)` in B2 and `=RIGHT(TRIM(A2),10)` in C2.

Now these are still strings. Normally I'd use DATEVALUE to convert the strings to dates, but my copy of Excel doesn't like those crazy nonsense* date formats. So we will parse the dates into the DATE function. Putting `=DATE(RIGHT(B2,4),LEFT(B2,2),MID(B2,4,2))` and `=DATE(RIGHT(C2,4),LEFT(C2,2),MID(C2,4,2))` into cells C2 and D2 respectively.

From here we can recombine them using the TEXT function (much like the format function in VBA) and some string concatenation into your original single-cell date range format. Assuming that's the desired result.

So our final cell, F2, would be `=TEXT(D2,"dd/MM/yyyy") & " - " & TEXT(E2,"dd/MM/yyyy")`. We could of course combine all those formulas into one big mess like so:

```
=TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(LEFT(A2,10),4),LEFT(LEFT(A2,10),2),MID(LEFT(A2,10),4,2)),"dd/MM/yyyy") & " - " & TEXT(DATE(RIGHT(RIGHT(TRIM(A2),10),4),LEFT(RIGHT(TRIM(A2),10),2),MID(RIGHT(TRIM(A2),10),4,2)),"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

### By Visual Basic for Applications

It's the same process here, just using VBA functions and syntax instead of Excel formulas.
Now for whatever reason the VBA version of DateValue will accept those dates in my copy of Excel. So I'll use it.

```
Public Function ChangeDateFormat(inputString As String) As String
  Dim firstDate As Date
  Dim secondDate As Date
  Dim trimmedInput As String
  trimmedInput = Trim$(inputString)
  firstDate = DateValue(Left$(trimmedInput, 10))
  secondDate = DateValue(Right$(trimmedInput, 10))

  ChangeDateFormat = Format(firstDate, "dd\/MM\/yyyy") & " - " & Format(secondDate, "dd\/MM\/yyyy")
End Function

Public Sub Test()
  Sheet1.[B2] = ChangeDateFormat(Sheet1.[A2])
End Sub
```

This can be tested either by running the provided Test sub, or ChangeDateFormat can be used as a user defined function in an excel formula `=ChangeDateFormat(A2)`.

Note, in the date formats passed to Format, I escaped the date separator `\/` instead of just putting `/` in. This is because the Format function will automatically replace `/` with the date separator from your Windows settings. And since I use a modern computer friendly date format, my seperators are dashes...

#### Footnote

* Life would be so much easier if people would just use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It exists for a reason, a good reason.

Comment: Thank You so much for your long and clear answer, shall try it out in a while =D