# How do I Convert from yy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy in vba excel?

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, I am not a shark at Excel or VBA. 
I have 18.000 objects in my excel and all of them is in the date format yy/mm/dd. 
My assignment says, that I have to make a sub/function in Excel, VBA, to convert all of the 18.000 objects into the date format dd/mm/yyyy. 
I have been searching on the internet, but I have not found any answers to this problem. 
So I would like to hear, if some of you has some guidance or answers for me. :)

Comment: First of all, you have not searched properly because there is around 50.000 examples doing this just googling for *Convert from yy/mm/dd to dd/mm/yyyy*. Second, do it manually in Excel while you use the macro recorder, and check the code you have generated. That's the way to go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668817/how-to-change-mm-dd-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-using-vba)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to use the macro recorder.

Comment: Use [Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) function in vba to convert date.